# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context Error in Flask Server

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use the flask server, but since I faced an error, I started debugging it and by removing many codes to simplify the code and find finally reached to the following error::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\SportsPersonClassifier\server\server.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(classify_image())
  File "C:\Code\SportsPersonClassifier\server\server.py", line 10, in classify_image
    response = jsonify(util.classify_image(util.get_b64_for_virat()))
  File "E:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 358, in jsonify
    if current_app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"] or current_app.debug:
  File "E:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 436, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "E:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 565, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "E:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

This is my code:: in server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import util

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/classify_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])


def classify_image():
    response = jsonify(util.classify_image(util.get_b64_for_image()))
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Python Flask Server For Sports Celebrity Image Classification")
    util.load_saved_artifacts()
    print(classify_image())
```

But the exact code works without any error, if I just remove jsonify() from the classify_image() function like this::

```
def classify_image():
    response = util.classify_image(util.get_b64_for_image())
    return response
```

If I write the classify_image function without jsonify it works as expected without error. I tried to solve the problem reading several StackOverflow answers but not working for my code. Please help me solve the problem with jsonify. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, and as required by [jsonify](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify):

> This requires an active request or application context

Calling the function this way via `__main__` will not be within a Flask app context. Instead use `app.run()` to start the dev server, and then navigate to your route.